# Problem with reflashing the compute module 3

Tags: compute-module-3

I got the *CM3* for it's size and power and I'm pretty new with how it works, so I got the *CMIO v1.2 dev board* the one without the sd card slot.

1. I plugged it in, installed the windows driver (I'm using Windows 8.1).
2. In the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-emmc-flashing.md) it says that I should see it as a mass storage device, but I didnt see it.

   - The `J4 pin` was already at the `EN` position.
3. Started *Balena etcher* and I selected the `CM3 4gb` option flashed the image on the *eMMC* and it booted and it worked ok.
4. Then I wanted to change the image, but the problem is my PC didn't recognize the *CMIO* board slave port after I flashed it.

**Q:** 
1. The CM3 can only be flashed only once? 
2. Or I messed something up? 
3. and I still don't know how to reflash it? 
4. Or if I can use an external SD card.